# Coin change memoization

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, memoization

Does the following algorithm to find all possible ways of making changes for a particular sum really use memoization?

```
func count( n, m )
  for i from 0 to n
    for j from 0 to m
      if i equals 0
        table[i,j] = 1          
      else if j equals 0
        table [i,j] = 0
      else if S_j greater than i
        table[ i, j ] = table[ i, j - 1 ]
      else 
        table[ i, j ] = table[ i - S_j, j ] + table[ i, j - 1 ]
return table[ n, m ]
```

Each time the function count is called, it starts filling the table from scratch. Even if the table's already been initialized for certain values, the next time count is called, it won't use these values, but will start again from i = 0 and j = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Memoization. This is an example for Dynamic Programming code.

In order to analyze your code, first we need to distinguish between Memoization and Dynamic Programming.

Memoization is a Top Down approach, where as Dynamic Programming is a Bottom Up approach.

Consider the problem of finding the factorial of a number **n**.

If you are finding n! by using the following facts,

```
n! = n * (n-1)! and 0!=1
```

this is an example for top down approach.

The value of n is kept in memory until the values of 0! to (n-1)! are returned. The disadvantage is that you waste a lot of stack memory. The advantage is that you don't have to recalculate sub problems if they are already solved. The solutions to sub problems are stored in memory.

But in your problem you don't have a top down approach, hence no memoization.

Every entry in the table is directly obtained from previously calculated sub problem solutions. There for it uses a bottom up approach. Hence you have a piece of code which uses dynamic programming.

Comment: Thanks, just as I suspected. The article where I found this algorithm claimed that it uses momoization.